# R plot: how to write superscript expression with greek letters?

Tags: r, expression, symbols, superscript

I am try to write "2 <sup>-ΔΔC<sub>T</sub></sup>" in a Y axes in a graph. Please, note the letter "T" is subscripted in the expression "-ΔΔC<sub>T</sub>".
This is the closest that I could do:

```
   plot + ylab(expression(paste("2"^{-ddC[T]})))
```

Do you have any better suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
plot(1, ylab=expression(2^{-Delta* Delta*C[T]}))
```

which produces...

[image]